# How can I replace Wildfly 9's default SessionManager with a custom implementation for all web apps?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, undertow

Based on my understanding of the Undertow docs and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528548/register-new-undertow-sessionmanager) stack overflow post,  I think I should be able to provide my own implementation of SessionManager.

I have created a jar file containing:

- a SessionManager implementation
- a SessionManagerFactory implementation
- a ServletExtension implementation
- a META-INF/services/io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension file
  containing the fully qualified name of my class

Have I done this right?  How do I get Undertow to pick this up?

Thanks

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar.  Do you have a complete example you can share how you got this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did all that, all you need is to have that jar in your war/WEB-INF/lib
and that is it.

When war is deploying WildFly will look for this ServletExtension and tell undertow to load it.

see also http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.2.0/index.html#servlet-extensions

Comment: Thanks that worked, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.  Rather than having the war know about the session manager I was hoping to have this managed at some wildfly configuration level and applied to all web app deployments.  Is this possible?

Comment: In theory, you can add it as a module in wildfly, and then import the module's `meta-inf` when declaring the module dependency.  You would need a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in each WAR to represent the needed dependency in your app.

Comment: At the moment there is no way to configure that via undertow subsystem configuration. But will probably be added in future versions.

Comment: Got it.  I was able to replace the session manager for each deployment using a solution inspired by John Ament.  I deployed my Jar to the modules directory and have my Ear deployment declare the dependency on my SessionManager implementation via its Manifest.  In other words the War's don't include the dependency and instead delegate the responsibility to the Ear deployment.